# Commit mutation in a different Vuex module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I got the following structure:

```
store.js
|
|-- yields.js
|
|--analysis (sub-folder)
          |
          |
          ---actions.js
          |
          ---mutations.js
          |
          ---state.js
```

In mutations.js I set the date of a state in state.js like:

```js
stateFetchParamsStart: (state, input) => {
  state.fetchParams.start = input;
  // Want to change yields.PRdate too
  //state.yields.PRdate = input;
}
```

How can I access the PRdate state of yields.js with the mutation from state.js?

---

EDIT with more information:

I'm setting initial values of `PRdate` when the component is mounted like:

```js
mounted(){
  ...
  this.fetchPRData(this.pvSystem.system_id); // makes an axios call
}
```

Also I've set a computed property asking for the date:

```js
getPrDate: {
  get(){
    return this.$store.state.yields.PRdate;
  }
}
```

Now when clicking on a date picker I want the date to change (also computed propery on a `v-model`):

```js
start: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.analysis.fetchParams.start
  },
  set(value) {
    this.$store.commit('stateFetchParamsStart', value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is yields a module too or is it the main store?

Comment: @Dan It is a module of the main store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change a Vuex module's state from another module, but it has to be done through an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html).  That action can call a mutation in the other module.  So first, create a mutation in your *yields* module:

```js
mutations: {
  statePRdate(state, input) {
    state.PRdate = input;
  }
}
```

Now you can use an action in the *analysis* module to commit that mutation.  Pass a third argument to the `commit` call:

```
{ root: true }
```

The first argument will be the *mutationName* or *moduleName/mutationName* if your modules are namespaced.  Here is the new action below that calls both a mutation in its own module and a mutation in another module:

```js
actions: {
  analysisAction({ commit }, input) {
    commit('stateFetchParamsStart', input);         // Commit in this module
    commit('statePRdate', input, { root: true });   // Commit in another module
  }
}
```

Initiate the action like:

```
this.$store.dispatch('analysisAction', 'input')
```

#### Namespaced modules

If your modules are namespaced, then you'd use namespaced syntax for both the commit and the action:

```
commit('yields/statePRdate', input, { root: true })
```

```
this.$store.dispatch('analysis/analysisAction', 'input')
```

Comment: It somehow doesn't work properly. I edited the actions.js with the analysisAction and added the mutation to yields.js.  Also I changed `this.$store.commit('stateFetchParamsStart', value)` to `this.$store.dispatch('analysisAction');`, but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Yea, I did. Theer's also no error - the value just won't change.

Comment: Try `this.$store.dispatch('analysis/analysisAction', value)`.  Make sure that the module names in the main store are "yields" and "analysis", and that both modules are `namespaced: true`

Comment: Checked that, but wasn't the mistake. Sadly still not working. I added more information to the question.

Comment: Best I can do is prove it with a demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/d49wronj/